# Find all the elements in Dih(2n), n odd, which commute with all other elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Look at this page:

http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/find-all-the-elements-in-dih2n-n-odd-which-commute-with-all-other-elements/

What is the “$q$” in the answer? And what "$0\leq a_0$" means? It's a typo. And I don’t understand the last 2 sentences: If $q≥2$ we have $2a<2n ≤ qn$, a contradiction. If $q=1$, we have $n=2n$ even, a contradiction.

Comment: Under the hypothesis that $x$ is a power of $r$, then $a$ must be $0\leq a\leq n-1$.

Comment: That page is pretty bad. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: who can help me understand what the proof in that page means?

Comment: Alexander has supplied a better proof. If you are not familiar with Alexander's notation $[x,y]$, it just means $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, and it yields the identity element if and only if $x$ commutes with $y$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that proof is very good, so I will explain the general case (for arbitrary $n$). Then if you like you can go back and figure out what the link is doing.

First, the presentation of $D_{2n}$ provides $r^s=r^{-1}$.  Thus we have $[r,s]=r^{-2}=r^{n-2}$, which, since $rs=sr[r,s]$, tells us that any given word in $r$ and $s$ can be written in the form $s^ar^b$, where $a=0$ or $1$ and $b=0,\ldots,n-1$.  (Why?)  Thus any $g\in D_{2n}$ has the form $g$ has the form $g=s^ar^b$.

You want to find which elements $z=s^{x}r^{y}$ so that $[z,g]=1$ for all $g\in D_{2n}$.  Let's calculate:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
[z,g]&=&z^{-1}g^{-1}zg\\
&=&(s^xr^y)^{-1}(s^ar^b)^{-1}(s^xr^y)(s^ar^b)\\
&=&r^{-y}s^{-x}r^{-b}s^{-a}s^xr^ys^ar^b\\
&=&r^{-y}s^xr^{-b}s^as^xr^ys^ar^b\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Note here that if $x=0$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&r^{-y}r^{-b}s^ar^ys^ar^b\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Obviously this is $1$ when $a=0$.  When $a\not=0$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&r^{-y}r^{-b}sr^ysr^b\\
&=&r^{-y}r^{-b}r^{-y}r^b\\
&=&r^{-y-b-y+b}\\
&=&r^{-2y}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
which is $1$ only when $y=0$ or $n$ is even and $y=n/2$.  A similar calculation for the $x=1$ case (which you should do) yields an expression which cannot be equal to $1$ for an arbitrary $x$ and $y$.  Thus the central elements of $D_{2n}$ are $1$ and $r^{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, or only $1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: What does $r^s = r^{-1}$ mean in the first line of the proof?  I'm not sure what $r^s$ would mean here.

Comment: @Rori $r^s\triangleq s^{-1}rs$. It's a group theory shorthand for conjugation.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I haven't seen that notation.